# C# MongoDb Driver, Cómo debería poblar un array?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, dotnetcore

Quisiera consultar referente a la consulta de datos de una base de datos en MongoDb.

Estoy aprendiendo al respecto, y la documentación se me hace un poco difícil de entender aún.

El asunto es que quiero traer algunos datos de una colección que contiene un array de Ids de otra colección.

En Javascript se utilizaría la instrucción **populate**, pero no entiendo aún como puedo utilizar **linq** o **Lookup** para obtener el mismo resultado.

Las entidades básicamente son:

```
public sealed class Person
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public String id { get; set; }
        public List<ObjectId> idsCodigoQr { get; set; } = new List<ObjectId>();
    }
```

y

```
public sealed class Qr
    {
        public Qr()
        {}

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public String id { get; set; }
    }
```

Para obtener las personas de la Db estoy usando:

```
var docs = _persons.Aggregate()
                     .Lookup("Qr", "id", "codigoQr", "asAccounts")
                     .As<MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray>()
                     .ToList();

            return docs;
```

pero obtengo el error

> System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the codigoQr property of class HCS.Models.Person: Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a HCS.Models.Qr value, but found a value of type ObjectId instead.

He intentado con **Linq** pero no entiendo como utilzar la instrucción **join** para poblar los datos en el array.

Básicamente tengo en db una lista de personas con el siguiente formato:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f5993182939e4f2446ed47a"
    },
    "name": "Pablo",
    "lastname": "Mederos",
    "codigoQr": [{
        "$oid": "5f59948f2939e4f2446ed47c"
    },
    {
        "$oid": "5f59948f2939e4f2446ed47c"
    }]
}
```

Existe alguna forma de poblar esa lista con los datos de la colección Qr?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente la solución fue:

```
 var result = ColeccionPersona.Aggregate()
        .Lookup(
            foreignCollection: ColeccionQr, //Colección foránea
            localField: person => person.codigoQr, //Lista de ids en la colección hija a obtener de la colección foránea
            foreignField: qr => qr._id, //Id en los objetos de la colección foránea
            @as: (Person p2) => p2.codigosArray //IEnumerable del modelo Persona en el que guardar los Documentos encontrados
            )
            .ToList<Person>(); //Personas que contienen los Documentos populados
```